# How much text can fit into a string.xml file?

Tags: android

Android: I am programming an app that is beginning to use a massive amount of text. I'm putting all of my text in a string file and calling it from there and then placing portions of it into a textview.

Is there a limit to that or is there a better way to store text (in a file or database?) and then retrieve it to go into a textview and if so...any examples?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using database to handle large amount of text.

It can handle unlimited text size.

You can use full text index in database to increase the search performance.

You may use view to select specific portions. Some databases support even [materialized view](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Materialized_view).